# python3 起動時のバージョン設定

Tags: python

python3 起動にて・・・
　-V　で　バージョン確認すると「3.5.1」　
　pyﾌｧｲﾙ実行で　バージョン確認すると「3.4.2」

（subprocess.runを使いたく）pyﾌｧｲﾙ実行でも　「3.5.1」　で実行したいのですが、どのように解消すれば良いのでしょう・・？

以下、参照

```
$ python3 -V
  Python 3.5.1
$ sudo python3 test5.py
  sys.version_info(major=3, minor=4, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
  3.4.2
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` によって、rootユーザーが認識している `python3` が起動されています。

OSにインストールされているPythonと、ユーザー環境にインストールされている(pyenvやanaconda等）のPythonバージョンが異なっていませんか？
Pythonインタプリタ上でどのPythonが実行されているかを知るには以下のように実行します。

```
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```